# How to see all the reachable nodes from a selected node in a directed graph in Gephi

Tags: gephi

I have a small directed graph which is a metadata basically. A single node is a table and an edge in this context means table1 feeds to table2 (query of table2 refers to table1). So when a certain table is impacted for some reason , I want to understand which all downstream tables are affected by this. So if a node A is affected , I want all the nodes reachable from that node. So say the node table is:-

```
Nodes = {A,B,C,D}
Edges = { (A,B) , (B,C) , (C,D) }
```

then if A is impacted , I want to see the entire impact list i.e. {B,C,D}.

I should be able to click on a given node in Gephi and it should highlight entire subgraph which the nodes reachable (since it's a directed graph) from the node I clicked on.

Comment: See "Ego network" in Gephi's topology filter folder.

Comment: Ego network seems to ignore the directions of edges,  [this post from 2013 agrees](http://forum-gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=3099) but provides no solution.